# Alturas de lo elementos HTML

Tags: html, css

Hay conceptos que no me quedan claros. Estoy trabajando con BootStrap 4 y lo que más dolores de cabeza da son los height. ¿Es cierto que hay un bug en los navegadores con el min-height?

Ejemplo, elemento padre le pongo la propiedad "min-height: 100vh", si al hijo en BootStrap le pongo la propiedad "h-100" no me hace caso. La única solución que encontre fue añadirle al padre la propiedad "Height: 1px".

¿Me podéis aclarar este asunto en si es un bug o está hecho a proposito por alguna razón? Gracias.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468066/child-inside-parent-with-min-height-100-not-inheriting-height/21836870

Comment: Pero en el mismo enlace indica estar resuelto https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559

Comment: Gracias entre que mi ingles es cortito y no habia visto la solucion...

Comment: Podrias ver tambien: https://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: Prueba de este modo: al padre colócale un `height: 100vh;` y al hijo le indicamos que herede la altura de su padre de este modo: `height: inherit;`